# Android Maps - animateCamera() method not working proper

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps-v2

Problem:

1) Map getting animated to reach the required location(4th line in code) but it got zoomed to the default location(5th line in code)

[leaving the map in the default location at the specified zoom level]

2) I understand why is the problem happening but i don't know how to resolve it.

3) If i change the 4th line to moveCamera instead of animateCamera that will work, but i do want animateCamera() method.

Here's the code:

```
map=((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
MarkerOptions options=new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(13.0810,80.2740));
map.addMarker(options);
map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(13.0810,80.2740)),4000,null);
map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15.5f),2000,null);
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The problem is that you call `zoom` right after you started animating to the new location. That's why it just replaces last camera update action with the new one.

You can simply resolve that by creating more accurate camera update action (which would include both latlng change AND zoom level change):

```
CameraPosition newCamPos = new CameraPosition(new LatLng(13.0810,80.2740), 
                                                  15.5f, 
                                                  map.getCameraPosition().tilt, //use old tilt 
                                                  map.getCameraPosition().bearing); //use old bearing
map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(newCamPos), 4000, null);
```

**ALTERNATIVELY** as pointed out by MaciejGórski, you can just use `newLatLngZoom` interface which includes both `LatLng` and `zoom` change:

```
map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(13.0810,80.2740), 15.5f), 4000, null);
```

Comment: Easier would be to just use newLatLngZoom version on the factory.

Comment: yeap, you'r right :) i'll update my answer with this option too

Comment: Note that animations don't work in lite mode, although a simple fade-in animation would have been nice

Comment: @LouisCAD what do you mean lite mode ? the free version ?

Comment: @ralphgabb Search what Google Maps Lite mode is. It's for static maps or use in lists for example

Answer (score 2):

Use [`CancelableCallback`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.CancelableCallback) with first `animateCamera` and call second `animateCamera` in `onFinish`.

Example: [AnimateCameraChainingExampleActivity.java](https://github.com/mg6maciej/android-maps-v2-demo/blob/master/NewMapsDemo/src/pl/mg6/newmaps/demo/AnimateCameraChainingExampleActivity.java#L58)

Answer (score 0):

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchLocation = async () => {
      const hasLocationPermission =
        Platform.OS === 'ios'
          ? await Geolocation.requestAuthorization('whenInUse')
          : await PermissionsAndroid.request(
              PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            );

      if (hasLocationPermission === 'granted') {
        await Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
          position => {
            const {
              coords: {latitude, longitude},
            } = position;

            setLocation({
              latitude,
              longitude,
              latitudeDelta: 1,
              longitudeDelta: 1,
            });
          },
          error => {
            // See error code charts below.
            console.log(error.code, error.message);
          },
          {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 15000, maximumAge: 10000},
        );
      }
    };

    fetchLocation();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (location && _map.current) {
      _map.current.animateCamera(
        {
          center: {
            latitude: location.latitude,
            longitude: location.longitude,
          },
          zoom: 15,
        },
        {duration: 5000},
      );
    }
  }, [location]);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <MapView style={styles.map} provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE} ref={_map}>
        {location && <Marker coordinate={location} />}
      </MapView>
    </View>
  );
};
```