# How to stop zooming in google map api 2 after updating current location every second?

Tags: android

I have developed an android app which get users current location at every second. but while updating location every second it zoom in by 2x at every update at every time so please help me to set constant zoom level which will not zoom after updating every second, I used this listener in onCreate

```
map.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(myLocationChangeListener); 

private GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener myLocationChangeListener = new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onMyLocationChange (Location location) {
        LatLng loc = new LatLng (location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        Bitmap bitmapicon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
        R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()))
            .title("My Location").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmapicon)));
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(loc, 5.0f));
    }
};
```

Comment: This probably has somthing to do with it: CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                                   loc, 5.0f)

Comment: I have already included this code CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom( loc, 5.0f) but its not working ,please let me know if you have any other idea

Comment: That part is the problem I think, not that you should added it. Because you have Zoom inside it, try to set it to CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom( loc, 0.0f)

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the

```
map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(loc, 5.0f));
```

to

map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(loc);

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(loc.getLatitude(),loc.getLongitude()), 5.0f));
```

see this for further reference [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16796645/android-maps-animatecamera-method-not-working-proper)

Answer (score -1):

You need to declare a **CameraPosition()** object like this:

```
mCameraPosition = new CameraPosition(mLatLong, 18, 30, 112.5F);
```

Have a look at the constructor [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/CameraPosition.html#pubctors)

```
CameraPosition(LatLng target, float zoom, float tilt, float bearing)
```

And finally pass this Camera position to your map like :

```
mGoogleMapOptions.camera(mCameraPosition);
```

Then pass the same zoom level when the location changes:

```
CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(LatLng, float)
```

So in this case your zoom level will be **18** along with the new location.
As stated on this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/views#moving_the_camera)